# Linear Recurrences and Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$$a_n = \lfloor\left(3+\sqrt5\right)^n\rfloor+1$$

Prove that for each n the number $a_n$ is divisible by $2^n$ without a remainder.

**Hints**

1. try to use the following sequence
   $b_n = (3+\sqrt{5}\,)^n+(3-\sqrt{5}\,)^n$
   and find a recurrence formula for $b_n$.
2. Use the fact that $0 < 3-\sqrt{5} < 1$

Edit: The minus sign in the sequence.

Comment: We have $a_1 = \lfloor 3+2.23 \rfloor +1 = 5+1 = 6$

Comment: What have you done on this?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: i think he means the Ceiling function not the Floor function

Comment: I found that $a_0=2$ and $a_1=6$ but don't know how to develop the formula.

Comment: For hint #1, try 
$b_{n+1}-b_n = (3+\sqrt{5})^{n+1}+(3-\sqrt{5})^{n+1}-(3+\sqrt{5})^n-(3-\sqrt{5})^n = (2+\sqrt{5})(3+\sqrt{5})^n+(2-\sqrt{5})(3-\sqrt{5})^n=2b_n+\sqrt{5}\left[(3+\sqrt{5})^n-(3-\sqrt{5})^n\right]$

Comment: I know that $3+\sqrt(5)$ is about 5.23, any power of that with 1 added should always give an even number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the recurrent sequence for $b_n$ is:
$$b_n=6b_{n-1}-4b_{n-2}, b_0=2, b_1=6.$$
Note that $b_n$ is an increasing sequence and its terms are always positive even numbers. Also, note that since $0<3-\sqrt{5}<1 \Rightarrow 0<(3-\sqrt{5})^n<1$, then:
$$a_n=b_n.$$

Comment: Hello, may I ask how did you find the recurrent series?

Comment: How did you find the sequence? and how did you jump to $a_n=b_n$?

Comment: Let $b_n=pb_{n-1}+qb_{n-2}$, then the characteristic equation is $x^2-px-q=0$, whose roots are $3+\sqrt{5}$ and $3-\sqrt{5}$. Can you find $p,q$?

Comment: 6 and -4, understood. And concluding to $a_n=b_n$ was done how?

Comment: Note that $b_n$ is a positive integer. So: $$b_n=\lfloor b_n \rfloor=\lfloor (3+\sqrt{5})^n+\underbrace{(3-\sqrt{5})^n}_{\in(0,1)}\rfloor=\lfloor(3+\sqrt{5})^n\rfloor+(\underbrace{\lfloor(3-\sqrt{5})^n\rfloor}_{=0}+1).$$